# What is an “enhancile”?

Tags: marvel, comics, powers

I have seen this term a few times in the following stories.

1. "[Black Summer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Summer)" by Warren Ellis.
2. "[No Hero](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Hero_(comics))" by Warren Ellis.
3. "[Absolution](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/ComicBook/Absolution)" by Christos Gage.
4. "[Iron Man](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man)".

As you can see, the term “enhancile” seems to appear most often in comic books. As far as I can tell, it seems to refer to people who have been enhanced in some way. I wonder if it is an alternative term for characters with superpowers without saying “superhero,” “supervillain,” and so on.

Does anyone here know what “enhancile” is supposed to mean?

Comment: It seems to be slang for "*an enhanced person"*

Comment: Hmm. I can guess why. It looks like "enhance" + "-ile," doesn't it? Usually, "-ile" is a suffix attached to adjectives and some nouns, and it means "tending to, or capable of." It usually appears with words derived from Latin. I hear that the term "enhancile" first appeared in "Global Frequency" #2 (January 2003). It's not part of the standard vocabulary, that's for sure!

Comment: I first thought it might come from the 1980's Marvel RPG by TSR, but the character creation I remember uses Altered Human (1986 version of the players handbook). There are a few later books which expand on the character creation, one of which may use the term enhancile.